# Checking ArcSDE Compatibility with SQL Server

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, esri-geodatabase, compatibility

I am trying to find if I can use ESRI sde 10.5.1 with a SQL Server 2016 SP1.

I am not able to find this information. What I've found so far:

- On the [Microsoft SQL Server database requirements for ArcGIS 10.5.x](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/databases/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm) page, it states that the 10.5.x version of ArcGIS is compatible with SQL Server 2016.
- The [ArcGIS Server 10.5.x system requirements](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/10.5/windows/arcgis-server-system-requirements.htm) page sends the user to the aforementioned page to get the info.
- The [Supported Environment Policy](https://support.esri.com/en/white-paper/3521) says that they usually support the main environments

Where or how can I find out if these two are compatible ?

(Note: The preferred answer would give the place where I can find this information, so that other users with different versions could use it too)

Comment: The documentation you cited ***is*** the definitive reference on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reach out to ESRI support to check if they are compatible.

Comment: So it turns out this is the correct answer, because there is no other resource available online. They told me that they are most likely compatible in the practice, but not officially so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is compatible, see here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/10.5/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm#GUID-0714EC60-B387-453D-A18D-6B4034196388

[image]

Comment: I see here that it is compatible with SQL Server 2016, not SQL Server 2016 SP1. If you look at the SQL server 2012, you'll see that the SP version is mentioned.